# jQuery clone a div and increment the ID but limit the clone to 3 times

Tags: jquery

I need to clone the div and increment the ID's but also limit the number of times cloned to 3.
Here is my code:

I have a button that will clone the fields in a div and increment the ID's.  This is working fine.  I want to add functionality that will only allow the user to clone 3 times; so the output would be `<div id="Outer_00">`, `<div id="Outer_01">` and `<div id="Outer_02">;` then on the 4th button click it would not clone.  Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ea5JE/  If the jsFiddle is not working here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var current_id = 0;
     $('#btn').click(function(){
         nextElement($('#Outer_00'));
     })

     function nextElement(element){
         var newElement = element.clone();
         var id = current_id+1;
         current_id = id;
         if(id <10)id = "0"+id;
         newElement.attr("id",element.attr("id").split("_")[0]+"_"+id);
         var field = $('input', newElement).attr("id");
         $('input', newElement).attr("id", field.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
         newElement.appendTo($("#elements"));
     }

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="elements">
 <div id="Outer_00">
 <input type="text" id="Field1_00" value="">
 &nbsp;
 <input type="text" id="Field2_00" value="">
 </div>
 </div>

 <button id="btn">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a check to see if you already reached your third element with id=2

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    if(current_id < 2)
        nextElement($('#Outer_00'));
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ea5JE/1/)**

Comment: Thanks the limiting is working great.  I have another problem.  When you clone the second and third set the elements are: Field1_01, Field1_01, Field1_01...it should be Field1_01, Field2_01, Field3_01; it is just cloning the first element 3 times and not each one. Any ideas?

Comment: @tjforce do you really need to set the ids for your inputs? I would just use the name attribute as an array like `elements[0][]` (or `elements[0][name]` for something more descriptive of your data) and increment the index when cloning so its easier to loop through the data server side

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/Ea5JE/3/)    I would do it like this...

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {

    var current_id = 0;
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        nextElement($('#Outer_00'));
    })

    function nextElement(element){

        if(current_id!=2){
        var newElement = element.clone();
        var id = current_id+1;
        current_id = id;

        if(id <3) id = "0"+id;
        newElement.attr("id",element.attr("id").split("_")[0]+"_"+id);
        newElement.data('id',id);
        var field = $('input', newElement).attr("id");
        $('input', newElement).attr("id", field.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
            newElement.appendTo($("#elements"));}
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var el = $('[id^="Outer_"]');
        if ( el.length < 3 ) {
            var clone = el.last().clone(true);
            clone.children().addBack().prop('id', function(_,ID) {
                return ID.slice(0,-1) + (parseInt(ID.slice(-1),10)+1);
            }).end().end().appendTo("#elements");
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ea5JE/6/)

Answer (score 0):

What about something re-usable, like:

```
function limit(func, max) {
    return function() {
        if (max > 0) {
            max = max - 1;
            return func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };      
};
```

And then:

```
var nextElement = limit(function(element) {
    //function body here
}, 3);

$('#btn').click(function(){
    nextElement($('#Outer_00'));
});
```

Here's a forked version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2RHXx/14/